# ¿Cómo desasociar un modelo con otro modelo en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Sucede que tengo dos modelos, uno llamado `User` y otro `Group`
Donde un usuario administrador puede crear grupos, y los demás usuarios participan en el grupo.
Sucede que tengo problemas en el momento de eliminar el grupo, pues debería desasociar al usuario del grupo en su columna `group_id`
Tengo en el modelo Group:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Y en el controlador que elimina el grupo y que debería desasociar el usuario es:

```
public function destroy( $id ){
        $group = Group::find( $id );
        if( $group->exists() ) {
            $group->users()->dissociate();
            $group->save();
            $group->delete();
            // User::where( 'group_id', $id )->update(['group_id' => null]);
            return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Grupo eliminado!'], 200);
        }
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'El grupo no existe.'], 422);
    }
```

Y en el foreing es:

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups')
                        ->onDelete('restrict')
                        ->onUpdate('restrict');
});
```

Aprovecho también en este post para preguntar acerca del

```
->onDelete('restrict')
 ->onUpdate('restrict');
->onDelete('cascade')
 ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

No sé como emplearlo correctamente, ¿como funcionaria para este caso? Uso el `restrict` pero aún no se cómo funciona ya que la documentación está en ingles :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No creo que dissociate sea posible en toda la colección de usuarios directamente. Se me ocurre puedes hacer un loop dissociando cada uno:

```
    $group = Group::findOrFail( $id );

    foreach($group->users as $user) {
        $user->group()->dissociate();
        $user->save();
    }

    $group->delete();
```

Para eso, en el modelo User debes tener definida la relación belongsTo con el grupo:

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
}
```

---

EDIT:
Aunque viendo la linea que tienes comentada, creo que puedes hacerlo mas eficiente en una sola consulta a base de datos:

```
$group = Group::find( $id );
User::where( 'group_id', $id )->update(['group_id' => null]);
$group->delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

Pienso que la manera mas simple de lograr lo que buscas es corregir la *integridad referencial* que declaraste en tu llave foránea, pues tienes esto:

```
->onDelete('restrict')
->onUpdate('restrict');
```

Lo cual se puede entender como:

Cuando intentes borrar un registro de la tabla padre, su correspondiente llave foránea en la tabla hija, no se eliminará pues esta regla `RESTRICT` lo impedirá.

Entonces para poder eliminar un Usuario y que quede desvinculado de un grupo tus *reglas de integridad referencial* deberían ser así

```
->onDelete('SET NULL')
->onUpdate('SET NULL');
```

¿por qué?

Para que cuando borres un usuario, su `id` que es llave foránea en la tabla `grupos` quede establecida a `NULL` quedando modificada la relación que existía entre ambos.

El detalle de esta respuesta, es que tu llave foránea debería poder ser `nullable` de este modo, para que aceptes precisamente valores de tipo `NULL`

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('llaveForanea_id')->nullable();
```

- [migraciones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations)